# On the integration of differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

In my notes the integration of a differential form on an oriented manifold $M$, with  $\{(U_\alpha,\phi_\alpha) \}$ oriented atlas, is defined as: $\int_M \omega = \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}}\int_M \omega_i$, where $\omega_i=\rho_i \omega$, where $\rho$ is a partition of unity subordinate to the cover $\{U_\alpha \}$. (For every $i$ there is $\alpha(i)$ s.t. supp $\rho_i$ is in $U_{\alpha (i)}$).

But why this sum is finite? I know that the set of supp $\omega_i$ is locally finite and $\omega$ has compact support but I think that I have however to sum on all $i$... Someone may help me?

Comment: In general, this sum is, of course, infinite. In particular, the integral may or may not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Finite sum $\ne$ finite number of summands. If $M$ is compact, you have a finite cover, so a finite number of summands. And consider the 0-form (function) $\omega(x)=1\ \forall x\in M={\Bbb R}$.

EDIT:
The partition of unity is required to define the integral. In each "patch":
$$
\int_{patch}\omega_i =\int_{{\rm subset of } R^n}\omega_i{\rm -composed-with-bijection}
$$
See http://www.math.cornell.edu/~sjamaar/papers/manifold.pdf, definition 12.1.

Comment: To be clear, though, the above sum does have finitely many non-zero terms, even when $M$ is not compact, right? Because we're assuming that $\omega$ is compactly supported and we're using a partition of unity... It's late where I am, so maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: In my hypothesis M isn't compact, but as @JesseMadnick say the support of $\omega$ is compact and the support of each $\rho_i$ is compact by definition on partition of unity. This means that $\omega$ is define only in a finite number of $U_{\alpha}$? And in each of these only a finite number $\omega_i$ is non zero, by the locally finite property??

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I know that the partition of unity is required to define the integral. My question in this post is how that sum are finite. there must be that only finitely many addenda are zero...But I don't know how conclude it with the property of partition of unity and $\omega$..

Comment: As studious said (see comment) and my example proves, a infinite number of nonzero summands is possible and the series can converge or diverge. If the support of $\omega$ is compact, you have a finite number of nonzero summands.

Comment: @andreasvr: I think you are assuming incorrectly that the sum of integrals always needs to be finite. Take the basic example of a non-compact manifold $M=\mathbb{R}$. Then the integral $\int_M x^2 \mathrm{d}x$ corresponds to the standard (Lebesgue/Riemann...) integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ x^2 \mathrm{d}x =\infty$.

Comment: Ok. So you say that with my hyp. the sum can be infinite? What I have to add to have a finite sum? M compact?

Comment: @PavelC and Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla: The OP is assuming that $\omega$ is compactly supported.  The functions $\omega(x) = x$ and $\omega(x) = x^2$ are not compactly supported on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @andreasvr, with compact support (or $M$ compact) you can cover $supp\omega$ with a finite number of $U_\alpha$ and the series has a finite number of nonzero summands.

Comment: @JesseMadnick in your opinion, how I can prove that only a finitely many indices are non zero?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla is what i wrote in second post?however  has a finite number of nonzero summands for the property of the partition of unity? could you explain me better how I can use this property in this case. Thank you so much

Comment: Yes, I overlooked your second commentary until several minutes later. If supp compact you can *choose* a partition of unit s.t. $\omega$ is nonzero only in a finite number of $supp\ \rho_i$.